# Swap blocks of memory

Tags: c++, memory

There are two different blocks of memory with different size. Is there a way to swap two equal-sized parts in both of them without allocating new memory?

Comment: Well.. at some point some memory needs to be allocated.. Otherwise you cannot save the old value before you write to it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure, just use [`std::swap_ranges`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap_ranges).  For example, if you have an `std::vector<int> v(100)` and an `int array[200];` you could do

```
std::swap_ranges(std::begin(v), std::end(v), array+50);
```

To swap the values in the vector with the values in the middle of the array.

To be specific about memory usage: if you have complex iterator or object types, you may need a stack frame for their comparison, dereference, or assignment operators.   Whether `swap_ranges` requires a stack frame of its own depends on the implementation.

In the example above, I would expect everything to be optimized out to a simple loop.  (I tried to profile it, but my simple testcase got optimized out to a series of `printf` calls.)